# Viewing details in installer created via NSIS is too slow

Tags: installation, nsis, packaging

I created some installation packages via NSIS. When i try to view the Details tab in file properties the details are loaded after a long time. I find this annoying as in general the Details for installers (from other sources) are loaded just within a second.

This is the piece of code in my NSIS script

```
Section
    SetOutPath $INSTDIR
    File /r "${VERSION}\*"
SectionEnd
```

Instead if i do a 7zip of required files and just extract it with NSIS, the details are loaded faster. i.e. instead of 'File /r "${VERSION}*"' i use the below set of instructions (ARCHIVE is a define for some 7z archive file).

```
    File "${ARCHIVE}"
    Nsis7z::ExtractWithDetails "${ARCHIVE}"
    Delete "${ARCHIVE}"
```

But the issue in above case is the required installation space displayed in the page is incorrect (shows the archive size instead of unzipped size)

How can this be resolved with NSIS?

Comment: Is it possible that your anti-virus is slowing it down?

Comment: In your second example, ${ARCHIVE} is probably wrong, you can't use the same path for File as the rest of the commands (and you should be using full paths for plug-in calls and Delete ($InstDir probably))

Comment: @Anders As mentioned in my comment ARCHIVE is a define for the 7z archive (actually it is full path). I've mentioned that my second example actually works (meaning Details Tab is loaded faster) unlike my first example. Also if anti-virus is a problem it should be same case for 2nd example too but it is not so.

Comment: You can't use the same full path define for File and Delete.

Comment: Try it in a different machine. The Delete path should start with $instdir or $temp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AddSize` to artificially inflate the size of a section:

```
Section
AddSize 5000
File ...
...
SectionEnd
```

You can also use `SectionSetSize` in `.onInit` as explained in the help file but this method is more complicated.

Comment: Yeah but its kinda manual work. I'm looking for additional option. It is unclear for me that why it behaves this way.

Comment: Why is that surprising? NSIS just knows the raw size of a file, it does not try to decompress files.

Comment: Correct. That is why i don't like to use it and go with the first example.